# Can't get reference of return value in Vb.Net

Tags: vb.net, reference, return

well I came from a lot of OOP language and seems VB.Net approach is kinda different

I have this function that returns a hashtable

```
   Public Shared Function getMsg(msgCode As String) As Hashtable
        Dim msgtable As Hashtable = New Hashtable

       'more and more codes were here...

        Return msgtable
    End Function
```

and I am trying to do something like this with the function call

```
 'where the function resides on a class named **common**
 common.getMsg("1").Item("ss")
```

but my visual studio IDE doesn't allow me to do the code above.

well in other languages like PHP, Javascript and other languages accepts this kind of approach but why VB.NET doesn't? if it doesn't accepts an approach like this then is their any workaround for this? thanks

Comment: Do not use the type `Hashtable`, consider it deprecated, along with almost all types in `System.Collections`. Use the types found in `System.Collections.Generic` instead.

Answer (score 0):

A VB.NET Hashtable is used this way... to add to the hashtable

```
Dim table As Hashtable = New Hashtable
table.Add("key", value)
```

To retrieve a value:

`table("key")` will work

you would pass in common.getMsg("1")

and it would return the value under key "1"

Comment: I am not trying to add something. what I want is to get something to the hashtable the is returned by my function

Comment: @Mahan, in order to put something in the hashtable you need to specify a key and a value and thats all you need.

Comment: I know already about that thing what I am asking is why is I can't return the reference of my hashtable on the function

Comment: Can you explain it a little better please. Right now you have a function that returns a hashtable. You have a hashtable within that function so I am assuming thats how you are trying to create something to return. What is the "1" you are trying to pass into the function to do. Is it looking for a hashtable with the key "1". If so is their a hashtable inside the hastable?